# Control's CssClass field changes on Init

Tags: asp.net, css, pageload

I'm working on someone else's code and found something very interesting and hoping someone might know how this is happening.

In the markup file, I place a `TextBox` control and a `DropDownList` control, and assigned both of them the `CssClass` of `InputField` which changes the background color and other cool stuff.

To avoid any doubts, here are my declarations, copy-paste verbatim from the IDE:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCity" CssClass="InputField" />
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlState" CssClass="InputField" OnInit="ddlState_Init" OnLoad="ddlState_Load" />
```

When I execute the page, I see the rendered `<input>` having the correct class name.
But the `<select>` has a class name `dropdown`, which just happens to be defined in another .css file in the project, that has different style than mine of course.

Once again, verbatim from the view-source:

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$BodyContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCity" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCity" class="InputField" />
<select name="ctl00$ctl00$BodyContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlState" id="ctl00_ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlState" class="dropdown"></select>
```

To find out how this happens, I stepped into each of the following events:

- `Page_Init`
- `Page_Load`
- `ddlStates_Init`
- `ddlStates_Load`

and added a watch to `ddlStates.CssClass`.
To my shock, I found that in all the events, the value of `CssClass` is already changed to `dropdown`.

What is changing the class name so early?
Can something I don't know about override values like this?
Even if something *does* change values, can it do that before the control's `Init` event itself?

**FYI**: The page class is not inheriting from any page base class - just straight-up `System.Web.UI.Page`.

**FYI**: I made sure that I *am* looking at the correct `ddlStates` instance by adding a random attribute and verified that it retains that information in all the event step-ins I did.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that you need to check before digging too much deeper. The first thing I would look for is a skin/theme file. These files overwrite the appearance of controls to make them feel consistent, but can play havoc when you don't know about them. To check this just look at your page header or take a look around for any skin files.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx) is a link with some more info on skin/theme files.

From the above source under the section Theme Settings Precedence:

> If you set a page's Theme property,
>   control settings in the theme and the
>   page are merged to form the final
>   settings for the control. If a control
>   setting is defined in both the control
>   and the theme, the control settings
>   from the theme override any page
>   settings on the control. This strategy
>   enables the theme to create a
>   consistent look across pages, even if
>   controls on the pages already have
>   individual property settings. For
>   example, it allows you to apply a
>   theme to a page you created in an
>   earlier version of ASP.NET.
>
> Alternatively, you can apply a theme
>   as a style sheet theme by setting the
>   page's StyleSheetTheme property. In
>   this case, local page settings take
>   precedence over those defined in the
>   theme when the setting is defined in
>   both places. This is the model used by
>   cascading style sheets. You might
>   apply a theme as a style sheet theme
>   if you want to be able to set the
>   properties of individual controls on
>   the page while still applying a theme
>   for an overall look.

If that isn't the problem then I would suggest changing the name of the drop down temporarily to make sure that it isn't being played with programmatically. If that fails then begins the long and arduous journey of debugging the hard way.

Comment: +1. Good tips/pointers. My money is on the CSS friendly adapters being the culprit.

Comment: That could certainly be the issue, really need a little more info to identify the real villian. Due the way skins are rendered it can catch a few people up but using the "less than friendly adapters" can be equally as confusing.

Comment: JonVD, it was exactly that; there's a .skin file which I never knew what it did.  Just to mess with me, that's all it does: apply the "dropdown" override!  Thanks a zillion!  I was going nuts!  I solved it by simply overriding it myself once again in Page_Load.

Comment: Note: you mentioned renaming the drop-down temporarily; no need -- I added that control myself, but it was being overridden magically, which is what drove me nuts...  how can it override things so dynamically even before the codebehind kicks in?  Little did I know that's what a .skin file does.

Comment: Thats great you got it sorted out, if that didn't work then you were in for a long few hours! Skin files can be great to get a consistent look to your controls but I prefer good ol' fashioned css personally, the devil you know as it were.